# Output search results into variable powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to output the search results from Get-QADGroup MSproject into a variable to then run Get-QADGroupMember on each returned result and output a count of how many userid's are in all groups combined, shown in a table.

I know I can export to a CSV and then import and Measure-Object as below:

```
Get-QADGroupMember MSprojectXP > C:\Temp\group2.csv
Get-Content c:\temp\group2.csv | Measure-Object -Line
```

And my output is:

```
 Lines Words    Characters     Property
 ----- -----    ----------     --------
   123
```

I was hoping someone could advise me on the best way to use a variable to complete the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get a count of the number of members in the group, you don't need a variable at all.

```
(Get-QADGroupMember MSprojectXP).Count
```

However, if you're going to need the member list for other processing, stash the results of `Get-QADGroupMember` in a variable:

```
$MSprojectXPUsers = Get-QADGroupMember MSProjectXP
```

Then you can get a count this way:

```
$MSProjectXPUsers.Count
```

---

Update based on comment/follow-up question:

```
add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement;
$TotalUsers = 0;
Get-QADGroup MSProject*|foreach-object{$TotalUsers += (Get-qadgroupmember $_.Name).Count};
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms");
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Total number of users in MSProject* groups`n`n$TotalUsers" , "Results");
```

My personal preference is to not use messageboxes when working with command-line scripts, as it's not "native" to the console environment. In which case, a one-liner suffices (linebreaks for clarity, assumes the snapin is already loaded):

```
$TotalUsers = 0;Get-QADGroup MSProject*|`
    foreach-object{$TotalUsers += (Get-qadgroupmember $_.Name).Count};`
    "Total users in MSProject* groups: $TotalUsers";
```

---

You can also try it without the Quest Snapin if you have the AD module available.:

```
$TotalUsers = 0;Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "MSProject*"}|`
    foreach-object{$TotalUsers += (Get-ADGroupmember $_.DistinguishedName).Count};`
    "Total users in MSProject* groups: $TotalUsers";
```

This isn't working for me, but that appears to be due to a problem with one of my groups - if I filter that one problem group out, it works fine.

Comment: Wow thats really helpfull, Thank you very much,

What would be the code if i had 3 groups that started with MSProject and i wanted to count them all and display counts in a msg box?

Comment: That'll be a bit more work, as `Get-QADGroupMember` can't take wildcards AFAIK. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @SeanPatrickColeman Updated. If the answer is correct & helps you, please accept it.

Comment: @SeanPatrickColeman Rather than posting comments saying "thank you" (which are often deleted by mods), the way to "thank" people who answer your questions at StackOverflow is to mark the answer that best resolves your question as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark to the left of the answer, and to upvote any other answers that you found helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: BTW, you do need at least 15 rep to vote. You had 6, I just gave you 5 more, and you'll get 2 more for accepting an answer, so you'll be almost there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks so simple that I probably don't know what you want, but if I am understanding correctly, this should work

```
$a=(get-qadgroupmember msprojectxp)

$a.count
```

or

```
$a=(get-qadgroupmember msprojectxp|select name)

$a.count
```

it just the same answer but more detail

$vGroupName="YourDomainName\msprojectxp"

$a=(get-qadgroupmember $vGroupName -type 'user' -indirect)

$a.count

this way you count all the nested members also
besides you have an array to work with and can output whatever you want from it